# Do building codes allow smaller nails when using gun instead of manually hammering?

Tags: framing

I would like to use a framing nail gun for a bathroom addition. Do people usually substitute a shorter nail for 16d 3.5", but keep the same quantity and spacing? Does that pass code?

Comment: Almost all framing nailers have the capacity for 3.5" nails. The only difference should be full or clipped head. Specific areas of the country may have codes requiring full heads, especially in hurricane or earthquake prone areas.

Comment: Thanks--I was curious because of how relatively few 3.5" collated nails there are for sale relative to some shorter sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Fastening schedules are quite straight forward. You look up what you're connecting together, and it tells you what size fastener to use, how many to use, the spacing between fasteners, and where the fastener should go.  There are no exceptions based on how the fastener is driven.

For example:

According to International Residential Code 2012, if you're going to end nail a top or sole plate to a stud, you'll use 2 16d (3 1/2″ × 0.135″) nails.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So if I understand you right, it's ok to use 0.135" nails where 16d is called for? This thickness is "box" rather than "common" thickness, right? I had gotten the impression that building codes required common.

Comment: From IRC 2012 Table R602.3(1) *a. All nails are smooth-common, box or deformed shanks except where otherwise stated.*.

Comment: Whoa, there it is in black and white in the table, 0.135 inches. So for that use, you MUST use a "box" diameter nail. I've been cramming code in prep for an ambitious bathroom addition--obviously I got my wires crossed somewhere along the line. I really appreciate being set straight--I raise a virtual beer to your knowledge!

Comment: To follow up for the record, I now see that table 2304.9.1 of the 2013 California building code lists penny sizes AND actual measurements (as done for collated nail sizes). For the stud to sole/top plate, it lists
(a) 2 - 16d common (3 1/2" x 0.162"); (b) 3 - 3" x 0.131"; (c) 3 - 3" 14 gauge staples.

I believe the LA County code prohibits the staples, but I'll have to dig around to see if I understood that correctly. Thanks again for helping me get a handle on this stuff.

Comment: @PhilEsra That sounds like International Building Code (IBC). If it's a residential application, International Residential Code (IRC) might be what's used instead.

Comment: Oy. True. Back to 602.3(1). You'd think IRC would be broader in fastener types specified. It seems incredibly weird to me that the code mostly doesn't match the nails you can buy in the store.